# Typescript apply+concat with a function argument

Tags: typescript

The following code compiles.

```
function myFunction(arg1:string, arg2:(msg:string)=>void){ /* do stuff */ }
var args = ["hello", function(msg){ /* do stuff */ }];
myFunction.apply(myFunction, args);
```

But the following code does not compile, even though the variable `args` is of the same type as above.

```
function myFunction(arg1:string, arg2:(msg:string)=>void){ /* do stuff */ }
var args = ["hello"].concat(function(msg){ /* do stuff */ });
myFunction.apply(myFunction, args);
```

It throws the following error.

```
>> src/workspace.ts(20,29): error TS2345: Argument of type '(msg: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

Any idea why?  Is this a bug in my code or a bug in the TypeScript compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TypeScript, when you create an array, the type is inferred from the array members. The following snippet is an `Array<string>`, or `string[]`

```
var a = ["hello"];
```

If you try to add another value to this array, it will have to be a string:

```
a.concat("A string");
```

If you added a function, it would warn you that it isn't compatible:

```
a.concat(() => { return 5; });
```

And this also applies in your example, even though you are doing it immediately, as you can tell by adding an allowable value:

```
["hello"].concat("A string");
```

You can get around this by widening the type of the array:

```
var args = (<any[]>["hello"]).concat(function(msg){ /* do stuff */ });
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  Since it returns a new array, I don't know if I agree with TypeScript's design decision of `.concat()` requiring its arguments to be of the same time as the array it was called on; it makes sense for something like `.push()` which modifies the existing array.  The workaround gets the job done though.